# Matlab Warning: Invalid string for Icon in MSGBOX

Tags: matlab, msgbox

I'm using the msgbox command to Show some Information for a short period of time.

```
handle = msgbox(sprintf('Trucks: %d',nT),'Fontsize',12);
pause(1)
delete(handle);
```

Doing this Matlab shows me the following warning:

```
Warning: Invalid string for Icon in MSGBOX.
```

Why is this string invalid? The Msgbox actually pops up and even shows the string perfectly. Any ideas?

Thank you !

Comment: That overload of msgbox() has *12* being interpreted as an Icon, which it isn't.

Comment: Ok, thx ! I got it. I did not notice that the Fontsize was not changed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to Alex K.'s comment, I want to show how I delete the warning but still changing the fontsize in the msgbox:

```
handle = msgbox(sprintf('Cars: %d',nC));
txt = findobj(handle,'Type','text'); 
set(txt,'Fontsize',20); 
pause(1)
delete(handle);
```

The msgbox is shown for 1 second with fontsize 20 and after will be deleted.